# What is the semantic difference between set builder notation and indexed unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying Hubbard & Hubbard's *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms* (5th Ed.). It states that there's a difference between set builder notation and indexed unions. However, I don't understand where this difference in meaning comes from.

Context (Chapter 0, p8):

$l_n \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the line of equation $y = n$.

In the sidebar, it states:

> Although it may seem a bit pedantic, you should notice that
>
> $\bigcup_\limits{n \in \mathbb{Z}} l_n$ and $\{l_n | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
>
> are not the same thing.
>
> The first is a subset of the plane; an element of it is a point on one
> of the lines.  The second is a set of lines, not a set of points.

Could someone give a simple explanation of the difference?

Comment: What's the difference between $\{a, b \} \cup \{b, c\}$ and $\{\{a, b\}, \{b, c\}\}$?

Comment: Suppose you have ten boxes of breakfast cereal, each of a different type. $\{l_n\}$ is a big box that you put all those ten boxes in. $\bigcup l_n$ is what you get if you pour all those boxes of cereal into one big box.

Comment: $l_n$ itself is a set which contains lots of points. So $\bigcup _\limits{n\in \mathbb Z} l_n$ is a set of all the points on the lines $l_n$ for integral n. So, the first one is a union of sets of points so is a set of points. But the second one  is a set of lines, as in, a set of (sets of points).

Comment: Oh, and to get  your case, set ten equal to infinity, the size of $\mathbb Z$. :-)

Comment: Thank you all, this all makes sense to me now.  The explanation by @CharlesHudgins is short and sweet, and I also like the more physical explanation via cereal boxes.